# Snowflake Split ~ How could I obtain the results formatted to use it in the where clause to filter the results?

Tags: split, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

SET TestVariable = 'Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4';

SELECT SPLIT($TestVariable,',');

--results

[   "Test1",   " Test2",   " Test3",   " Test4" ]

--desired results

('Test1',   'Test2',   'Test3',   'Test4')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Snowflake Functions used with hyperlink to documentation:

- [LISTAGG()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/listagg.html)
- [SPLIT_TO_TABLE()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_to_table.html)
- [TRIM()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/trim.html)

  ```
    SELECT 
        '('||LISTAGG(''''||TRIM(value)||'''',',')||')'  VOLIA
    FROM 
        TABLE(SPLIT_TO_TABLE('Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4', ','))
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The approach is to use `SPLIT_TO_TABLE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table
WHERE some_column IN (SELECT value FROM SPLIT_TO_TABLE($TestVariable, ','));
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is [**arrays_overlap**](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/arrays_overlap.html).

```
where arrays_overlap([some_column],split($var,','))
```